# Java - Write Excel Using POI, CPU consuming

Tags: java, apache-poi, cpu-usage

My program generate some Excel using apache POI.

This part take up 50% of CPU for 1 excel..

If users generate at the same time multiple excel the server is out...

How can i reduce it ?

```java
            final Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
            initDataFormat(workbook);

            EnumMap<BomXlsSheetEnum, Sheet> sheetMap = sheetMap = BomXlsSheetEnum.getSheetMap(workbook);

            buildBomSheet(sheetMap, bom, productModelIds, listSizes, false);

            workbook.write(response.getOutputStream());
```

Comment: At first determine what exactly is that much resource consuming. Then optimize the code behind either `initDataFormat` or `BomXlsSheetEnum.getSheetMap` or `buildBomSheet`, dependent on your results from the first step.

Comment: This method create just the excel.
With createRow createCell etc.. I don't know how i can do that otherwise..

Any tricks to reduce memory consumption / cpu consumption with the POI library ?

Comment: Use profiler such as yourkit or visualvm